# How to create nested menues dynamically in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template

suppose main menu nav1 containing items ni1,ni2,ni3 and each of these itmes containing their sub menues.
so please guide how to create main menu and its sub menues in angular 2.0

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Can you show me in which format you are having the nav structure?